# PHP error unexpected T_ISSET

Tags: php, isset

I am getting an error in my activate.php code is below

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['u']) && isset($_GET['e']) isset($_GET['p']) {
   include_once("pathname");
    $id= preg_replace("#[^0-9]#i","",$_GET['id']);
    $u = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9]#i","",$_GET['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_GET['e']); 
    $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_GET['p']); 
   if($id == "" || strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($e) < 5 || $p == ""){
     header("location: message.php?msg=activation_string_length_error");
     exit();
   }
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND email='$e' AND password='$p' LIMIT 1";
 $query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
 $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows == 0){
     header("location: message.php?msg=Your Creditentials are not matching anything in our  system");
    exit();
  }
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET activated='1' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
  $query= mysqli_query($dbconx,$sql);
  } else {
   header("location: message.php?msg=missing_GET_variables");
   exit();
   }
 ?>
```

Not sure why I am getting this message at all? It says it is line 2 that there is an unexpected T_ISSET which I don't have any of those I don't think, I'm fairly new to PHP so if someone could explain to me if you find the error what I did?

Comment: ok if the error says line two then it's line two!, you have two issues with your syntax:
1- missing `&&` for the last `isset`

2- you have missing `)` at the end of your if expression


and here we go with thousands of answers

Comment: At least two people with complete answer @MaveRick and my answer!, and yet I got downvoted at some point :)

Comment: Yes I see that now ;) A lot of answers and a lot of low blows to me. Completely overlooked the line 2. I mean I knew it was line two but I had other errors as well like `isset($GET['e'])` is how I did all my get parameters. Honest mistake :D

Comment: you can group the vars in one `isset()` like `isset($_GET['a'], $_GET['b'], $_GET['c'], etc....)` since the `isset()` function deal with many given vars as `&&` and all given vars should return `true` so the `isset()` function return `true`

Comment: Hey thanks MaveRick! Great suggestion and great learning point ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statement is the culprit, you're missing closing parenthesis and missing logical operator `&&`:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['u']) && isset($_GET['e']) && isset($_GET['p'])) {
```

Missing closing parenthesis for `if` and logical operator `&&` before the last `isset`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an && and closing  missing in

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['u']) && isset($_GET['e']) isset($_GET['p']) {
```

Should be

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['u']) && isset($_GET['e']) && isset($_GET['p'])) {
```

Thanks

Comment: Wow I literally just looked at this for about thirty minutes and completely overlooked the last `&&` before I had it `isset($GET['e'])` doe all of them. Like I said I am new :D

Comment: I'll be upvoting all of those who had the correct answer. Please take away my downvotes guys. It's an honest mistake

Comment: @EasyBB You also had closing ) missing

Comment: @EasyBB: I didn't downvote your question but... many similar questions have been asked and answered before. When you encounter a syntax error, the first step should be to *google* it. That way, you'll save time (and criticism for not doing basic research)

Comment: @AmalMurali I did google it, a lot were saying issues with the GETs which I fixed of course, not the logicals though. As well as some were saying the Database connection could be wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

You missed a [logical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) between `isset($_GET['e'])` and `isset($_GET['p'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['u']) && isset($_GET['e']) isset($_GET['p']) {
                                                             ^^^^---here
```

You forgot the logic operator, probably `&&`.